# Runtime.exec() no output

Tags: java

Code that runs 4 'Street' processes:

```
for (int i=0; i < NUM_STREETS; i++) {
        Process process = runtime.exec("java -classpath \\bin trafficcircle.Street 1 2");

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.flush();
        }

        InputStream es = process.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader(es);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(esr);

        while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.flush();
        }

        int exitVal = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    }
```

Where 'Street' is:

```
public class Street {

/**
 * @param args
 * 0 - Simulation run time
 * 1 - Flow time interval
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    System.out.println(args[1]);
    System.out.flush();
}
```

}

Prints out:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class trafficcircle.Street
Process exitValue: 1
Error: Could not find or load main class trafficcircle.Street
Process exitValue: 1
Error: Could not find or load main class trafficcircle.Street
Process exitValue: 1
Error: Could not find or load main class trafficcircle.Street
Process exitValue: 1
```

'Street.class' in my Eclipse project is under \bin in package trafficcircle. I thought Runtime.exec would complain first if it wasn't found...what's up with this?

Comment: Have you tried to System.out.flush()?  On both ends?

Comment: Just did, as edited, but still nothing.

Comment: Have you tried running that command from the prompt? Try reading the error stream of the subprocess and see if anything helpful is being printed to that.

Comment: I edited above: added answer suggestions and resulting output. Any more ideas? (This is my first time using this kind of stuff)

Comment: You definitely have a mess with your `.class` file location. Give an an overview of your directory structure (I suppose you have `bin\trafficcircle\Street.class` file at location starting from your project)?

Comment: Thanks all. This was resolved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106689/runtime-exec-gives-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are getting an error which you are discarding. Try using `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);`

When you try to run a command it is not run in a shell, and may be getting an error which you don't see on the command line. I would explicitly use

```
"java","-classpath","bin","trafficcircle.Street","1","2"`
```

and make sure you are getting any error messages.

another option is to use a shell like

```
"/bin/bash", "-c", "java -classpath bin trafficcircle.Street 1 2"
```

Comment: You are not right with your guess that Java treats the passed argument as executable name: `Runtime#exec(String)` function passes the argument to `Runtime#exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` which performs the command tokenization. My advises would be to check the exit code.

Comment: +1 hadn't thought of invoking `/bin/bash` with `-c`. I like it :)

Comment: wont `\bin` refer to a folder named bin in the root dirctory of whatever hard disk you are running the program from? I believe any path beginning with a slash means it starts from the root location, even in windows. If you want to refer to a bin directory in your eclipse project (and assuming you were trying to put the relative path) you could try "bin\" or just "bin". Better yet put the full explicit path. Unless I misinterpreted what you meant by "'Street.class' in my Eclipse project" which sounds to me like you want a different bin folder than the root one.

Answer (score 0):

Use ./bin (with a dot) to use relative paths.