# Runtime.exec() gives Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

'Street.class' in my Eclipse project is under \bin in package trafficcircle. The error below is from stderror of the created process; I thought Runtime.exec would complain first if it wasn't found...what's up with this?

Code that runs 'Street' process:

```
    Process process = runtime.exec("java -classpath \\bin trafficcircle.Street 1 2");
```

Where 'Street' is:

```
public class Street {

/**
 * @param args
 * 0 - Simulation run time
 * 1 - Flow time interval
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    System.out.println(args[1]);
    System.out.flush();
}
}
```

Process prints out:

Error: Could not find or load main class trafficcircle.Street

Process exitValue: 1

And yes, this works on cmd line:

C:\Users\Brent>java -classpath "D:\Java Programs\IPCTrafficCircle\bin" trafficcircle.Street 1 2

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Runtime.exec()` to run Eclipse-generated code with `java.exe`? FYI, Eclipse has a run button. I don't see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Where did you run the class that have `exec(...)` command?

Comment: So I don't have to press the run button several times every time I want to test. This program will be an inter-process communication simulation that creates processes and has them communicate (for school).

Comment: wannik, that code is in my Eclipse project\bin\Main.class. I just press the eclipse run button to run Main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gives the expected result when run in the folder `/bin` by typing the command line `java Test`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "java trafficcircle.Street 1 2");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't give any result when run in Eclipse. To get the result, I have to set the class path.

```
"java -cp /Users/wannik/Java/Workspace/MyProject/bin trafficcircle.Street 1 2");
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I have to use the full path as well in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec()` would complain if *java* wasn't found, which is the process you are running. The message you are reading is coming from that process' output.

Do you notice a difference between what you're exec'ing and what you say works on the command line? *That's* the problem.

The java JVM you are exec'ing needs to be able to find the class you want it to run. The classpath you are giving it (`\bin`) isn't correct.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't see my project as working directory and thus I can't use a relative path?

Comment: `\bin` is not a relative path, it's an *absolute* path. `.\bin` would be a relative path if that's the way you have things structured.

Comment: Yep, using an absolute path works...but won't work on across machines.